# Analysing a rating question

Tags: ordinal-data, likert

In a survey done to find the characteristics consumers prefer while choosing a retail store.   Respondents were given 9 options  and to scale them from 1-10 one for the most preferred value. Now we have responses in which respondents have given same ratings to multiple characters. Example given:

```
price             1
quality           1
variety,          3
customer service  1
store design      9
```

Like wise mentioned above. How do we analyse this?

Comment: Peter offered many useful ideas but in general, the analysis would depend on what you want to learn from the data and what you know or are willing to assume about the process generating them. There isn't one true way to analyze ratings.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things you could do. For example, you could look at the median rating of each attribute, with the idea that higher median ratings would be more important in general.

You could also look at the proportion of raters of each attribute who give it a high rating, on the theory that the things that matter in choosing a store are the items that the person things are important.

You could do cluster analysis on the ratings, with the idea that perhaps clusters of people see sets of factors as important.

You could do multidimensional scaling on similarities of ratings, to get at latent factors in the data.

If you also have data on which stores the respondents *actually* shop in, that leads to other possible analyses. If you have data on how much people *spend* then, again, there are more possible analyses.

(That's just off the top of my head).